# Making network call from webview in vscode-extension

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is it possible to make a network call (using axios or other libs/options) using latest webView API for VSCode extension? I couldn't find any clear documentation on this, so any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered the answer after a bit of digging into the docs,  you would need to enable certain options while creating the webview. For my use case, I ended up with following options enabled:

```js
{
    enableScripts: true,
    retainContextWhenHidden: true,
    enableCommandUris: true
}
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/webview

Comment: Only `enableScripts` is required for running scripts. Only set the other two options if you have a very good reason to

Comment: could you please share an example of how you archived this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, normal browser apis like `fetch` should work fine in webviews. To run a script that makes a network request in a webview, just set the `enableScripts` webview option and embed the script in your page somehow (preferably as an external resource and not inline)

A few things to keep in mind:

- Webviews are run in their own context so you cannot access `localhost`.
- Always set a content security policy so that the webview only loads resources from trusted sources.
- Always use https